# jQuery File Upload "Error - Empty file upload result" - Rails Application

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, file-upload

I don't get why I'm getting this error? I've copied exactly from the source code example. I'm able to get everything loaded, and then when I try to upload (by clicking start), I get this error.

[image]

But even if I'm getting this error, it still uploads to my database correctly. When I refresh my page, I have a show page that will display the uploaded images, and it's there. What's causing this issue?

Please help! I'm also using paperclip to upload. In my environment, I'm uploading locally, but in production, I'm uploading to Amazon S3

This is what my controller looks like when creating or updating the form.

```
def create
  @project = Project.new(project_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @project.save

      if params[:photos]
        params[:photos].each { |image|
          @project.project_images.create(photo: image)
        }
      end
      format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def update
  @project = current_user.projects.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @project.update(project_params)

     if params[:photos]
        params[:photos].each { |image|
          @project.project_images.create(photo: image)
        }
      end     

      format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @project }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

EDIT:

Here's my form

```
<%= simple_form_for @project, html: { multipart: true, id: 'fileupload' } do |f| %>

<span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
    <span>Add files...</span>
    <input type="file" name="photos[]" id='photo_upload_btn', multiple>
</span>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
    <span>Start upload</span>
</button>
<button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
    <span>Cancel upload</span>
</button>

<% end %>
```

Edit:

jQuery Code

```
<script>
$(function () {

    'use strict';

    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload();
        // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
        //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},     
    });
    // Load existing files:
    $('#fileupload').addClass('fileupload-processing');
    $.ajax({
        // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
        //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
        dataType: 'json',
        context: $('#fileupload')[0]
    }).always(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('fileupload-processing');
    }).done(function (result) {
        $(this).fileupload('option', 'done')
            .call(this, $.Event('done'), {result: result});
    });
});
</script>

<script src="http://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Templates/js/tmpl.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/js/load-image.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob/js/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/js/jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you post the `Jquery` code for fileupload?

Comment: @Pavan posted :) thanks for helping!

Comment: I am not an expert, so just curious. Why do you don't have ajax type specifyd? Is there a default type?

Comment: why dont you check what response you are getting in the `}).done(function (result) {` part, i mean the `result` and see if it is like the one needed by the plugin?

Comment: @hellomello, Have you ever tried my answer below

Answer (score 7):

[jQuery File Upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)  has specified JSON response [mentioned here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Setup#using-jquery-file-upload-ui-version-with-a-custom-server-side-upload-handler).

Extend your create method to return a JSON response akin to the following output:

```
 {"files": [
  {
    "name": "picture1.jpg",
    "size": 902604,
    "url": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/picture1.jpg",
    "thumbnailUrl": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/thumbnail\/picture1.jpg",
    "deleteUrl": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/picture1.jpg",
    "deleteType": "DELETE"
  },
  {
    "name": "picture2.jpg",
    "size": 841946,
    "url": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/picture2.jpg",
    "thumbnailUrl": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/thumbnail\/picture2.jpg",
    "deleteUrl": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/picture2.jpg",
    "deleteType": "DELETE"
  }
]}
```

Also in case of error, just add an error property to the individual file objects:

```
{"files": [
  {
    "name": "picture1.jpg",
    "size": 902604,
    "error": "Filetype not allowed"
  },
  {
    "name": "picture2.jpg",
    "size": 841946,
    "error": "Filetype not allowed"
  }
]}
```

The easiest way to do this is add following code to your Photo model [see here](https://github.com/bigos/chrisb-images/blob/master/app/models/photo.rb)

```
  def to_jq_upload
    {
      "name" => read_attribute(:attachment_file_name),
      "size" => read_attribute(:attachment_file_size),
      "url" => attachment.url(:original),
      "thumbnailUrl" => attachment.url(:thumb),
      "deleteUrl" => "/photos/#{self.id}",
      "deleteType" => "DELETE" 
    }
  end
```

and your JSON response should be like this [see here](https://github.com/bigos/chrisb-images/blob/master/app/controllers/photos_controller.rb)

```
format.json { render json: {files: [@photo.to_jq_upload] }}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for me :(  Maybe jquery isn't my thing. I changed jquery to just nested attribute, but it would be nice to have it working.